# About Team Build and building Web Sites, custom code activity problem

Tags: msbuild, web, build, tfsbuild

I'm trying to Publish a Web Site using Team Build 2010, but I didn't see any easy options out there. So I tried to create a custom activity which calls a process in the agent ("aspnet_compiler.exe") with my parameters and publish my site.

I can delete folders, create folders, compile and build projects...

But this process just doesn't start on the agent when I call it... what is the problem?

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
        // string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "aspnet_compiler.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-p "+context.GetValue(this.SourcesDirectory) +
               " -v / " + PublishDirectory;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        while (!proc.HasExited)
        {
        }

        context.SetValue(Result,proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Is there any other way to build/publish web sites? What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: I have the same problem using invokeprocess on aspnet_compiler. I can get anything to work with invokeprocess except the aspnet_compiler. It is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time TFS builds a project/solution, it automatically publishes web projects/sites and place them in a folder named `_PublishedWebsites`. You can easily use it.

Additionally if you need to copy/move this folder to another place or even if you need to do this with other file/folders, you can use `CopyDirectory`, `DeleteDirectory` and other Team Foundation Build Activities. If you still need to run something during build process, you can use `InvokeProcess` build activity instead of creating your own build activity.